# Get taxonomy url, name, post count & image

Tags: taxonomy, terms, images, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I'm attempting to display a specific taxonomy (channel) in the archive.php page. I want to display the taxonomy's URL, name, post count, and taxonomy image.

This is what I have that's working so far:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'channel';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
$image_url = print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' );
?>

<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) { ?>

        <li>
            <?php echo esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)); ?>
            <?php echo $tax_term->name; ?>
            <?php echo $tax_term->count; ?>            
            <?php echo $image_url->image_id; ?>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

I've gotten URL, name and post count working, the part that's not working is the taxonomy image provided by the Taxonomy Images plugin. (in the snippet, it's $image_url)

https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/

The plugin provides a image_id for an image added to a taxonomy, the plugin has a ton of ways to get the ID and display the image but I just can't seem to find the correct combination to work with my snippet with my level of skill.

Need some help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don´t know how this plugin works in detail but i would try this:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'channel';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>

    <ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) { ?>

        <li>
            <?php echo esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)); ?>
            <?php echo $tax_term->name; ?>
            <?php echo $tax_term->count; ?>             
            <?php print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' ); ?>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: That didn't work but thanks, I found a better way, placed the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a better option.

Instead of using Taxonomy Images plugin, Instead, I opted to use the more widely used Categories Images plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/

The working code below:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'channel';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);

foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) { ?>

    <div class="column">
        <?php echo esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)); ?>
        <?php echo $tax_term->name; ?>
        <?php echo $tax_term->count; ?>             
        <?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($tax_term->term_id); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```